# The Great Philosophy.SE Tag Cleanup of 2012

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tags have grown a bit messy. Let's get together and clean them up! Please find a list below of meta-tag candidates for cleanup. Feel free to suggest others in answers! I'll plan to keep the list updated as the cleanup proceeds.

**Cleaned-up tags**:

- [thought-experiment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thought-experiment)
- [definition](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) *(merged/made synonym of [terminology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology))*

**Deferred and declined candidates for cleanup**:

- [terminology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) *(cleanup declined)*
- [reference-request](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) *(cleanup deferred pending review)*
- [debate](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debate) *(cleanup deferred for the time being)*

Note that another aspect of the cleanup will be amplifying tags as well, trying to more precisely identify questions and so on. If you have candidates for new tags, an answer might be a good place to make your case for it.

Happy retagging!

Comment: Good idea, sir!

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents:

## Keep

- [terminology](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) I think this can be useful, in the sense that a user might be asking for the term for a particular concept or idea.

## Toss

- [thought-experiment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thought-experiment) is questionably useful. Everything in philosophy can be thought of as a thought-experiment in something. Probably a good candidate for deletion.
- [definition](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) Since we don't typically encourage definition questions, this could probably be removed.
- [debate](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debate) useless; philosophy is one giant debate. I vote delete.

## Needs more discussion

- [reference-request](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) I'm in agreement that the this tag is somewhat ambiguous and seems to allow users to ask questions which they would normally be discouraged from asking. Either way, the tag is not overly useful; the question comes down to whether we allow those types of questions.

Comment: I have updated the list, marking [tag:terminology] as declined. As to [tag:reference-request] -- why don't we have a separate question asking users to vote on the site policy with respect to reference requests, and put some potential policies as answers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the tagging system works, as when I click in "contradiction", I get some questions that do not show this tag, but "logic" instead.
I'd suggest that things like "contradiction", "induction", "deduction", "fallacies" and "paradox" would be resumed to "logic". If this is not the case, then I think it would be nice to add the tag "logic" to the questions stating only "induction", for example.

I think there should not be tags for names of particular works like "Critique of pure reason", "The republic", "The prince"; I consider these should be tagged "Kant", "Plato" and "Maquiavel" instead.

Please let me know if there's something wrong behind my reasoning, as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Bumping this thread.

I've been sorting through questions with the "terminology" tag.

Some seem to be a good fit. In other cases, it seems completely unnecessary and counterproductive as a tag.