# Ideas for annual cleanup?

Tags: discussion, community, housekeeping

We are hovering very close to our graduation goals, so it might be a good idea to have another round of yearly housekeeping.

[Historically we have done things like cleaning up tags](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/the-great-philosophy-se-tag-cleanup-of-2012), but it would be interesting to explore other things.

> What sort of things should we focus on for our annual cleanup?

Comment: As a general remark: be careful with batch edits to not flood the main page. Just edit a few at once.

Comment: @Keelan thanks for this reminder. I think I might've gotten a bit carried away...

Comment: I really just meant generally, didn't see you were doing something :)

Answer (score 3):

**Fix headlines so they are questions**

[This data explorer query shows questions without question marks at the end of their title](http://data.stackexchange.com/philosophy/query/415514/question-titles-without-question-marks).

It would be great to try to fix a lot of them at once. Another thing to look out for here might be questions with "this" in them ([this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/philosophy/query/424670/question-titles-with-this) might help).

---

We started with north of 1400 questions that didn't end in question marks as measured by the query above (almost 25% of all questions). I'll log our progress in driving that number down here. I think the cache that drives explorer query results is cleared weekly.

**12/27/2015**: We're down around 1340.

**1/3/2016**: 1287

**1/10/2016**: 1167

**1/17/2016**: 1086

**1/24/2016**: 1059

**2/15/2016**: 994 -- We're below a thousand!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [writing a policy like Skeptics.SE](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3024/2953) would be a nice idea for the coming time.

We could collect ideas in another meta post, vote on them for some time, then write the policy as a separate post to put everything together. That way, it's clear what is policy (second post) and what is just some meta user's opinion (answer on first post).

Or we could do this a different way.

Answer (score 2):

To systematically go through the [list of unanswered questions](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered), to see if questions should be edited, closed or maybe to answer them is a good way to increase the answered% (which counts towards the graduation criteria). It maybe doesn't count as clean-up per se, but is useful to increase the quality of the site. At BioSE we had a couple of rounds of this before graduation, which pushed up our answered% several points and also highlighed a couple of really good unanswered questions that had been forgotten, by bumping them in the activity queue.